# Where can I find a list of all possible badges?

Tags: support, badges

Is there an overview of all badges you can earn and, if yes, where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a list of all badges here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

This page is also linked from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help); click on "View a full list of badges you can earn" under the "Badges" heading.

To see the specific badges that you've earned, go to the "Badges" tab in you profile page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=badges).